# Dataflow (TPL): How randomly process consecutive data

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

Given

- This code represents some module/service
- The module receives a group of items each time and start process it
- The module should's wait for previous groups to complete to start processing the new one (only CPU limitations)

The output of the code below is: `000000000011111111112222222222`

Hot to change the code to make next output: `012012012012012012012012012012`?

```
    var executionDataflowBlockOptions =
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { 
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3, EnsureOrdered = false, BoundedCapacity = 30 };

    var testData =
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, 3)
            .Select(o => Enumerable.Repeat(o, 10));

    var inputBlock =
        new TransformManyBlock<IEnumerable<int>, int>(
            collectionOfItems => collectionOfItems, 
            executionDataflowBlockOptions);

    var processBlock =
        new ActionBlock<int>(
            number =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.Write(number);
            }, 
            executionDataflowBlockOptions );

    inputBlock
        .LinkTo(processBlock);

    foreach (var item in testData)
    {
        await inputBlock.SendAsync(item);
    }
```

### UPDATE (EnsureOrdered)

Finally found this option (thanks JSteward). I used the 
**Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow** (which looks obsolete) instead of **System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow**. Not sure why nuget search brings them in a such strange order.

Anyway adding this option changes results. Sometime it outputs 000000000022222222221111111111 (changes order groups), Changing the BoundedCapacity=30 sometime output such results: 210202222222020000000111111111 or 201012222222212111111001000000, which is much better, but still results can be more random

Comment: I think you should use `Task.WhenAll`. (I didn't give you the downvote.)

Comment: @Kamarey You can set `EnsureOrdered` to `false` and that will allow items to propagate when ever they're ready. But you still won't get `012012` and your desired output seems to contradict your last requirement that groups must wait to be processed. Can you elaborate what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: @JSteward: I can't find the EnsureOrdered option (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). I want to start to process the group 3 before group 1 and 2 finish processing. E.g. that the processBlock will take items from all groups. I don't mean the exact order 012012, but the idea that 2 can be processed in parallel with 0 and 1 groups.

Comment: @Kamarey `EnsureOrdered` isn't listed in MSDN as you saw but you can [see it here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlockOptions.cs). There was also a long discussion on what to name that option but I can't find it at the moment. Just make sure you are using the latest `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` nuget package and the option will be available. If memory serves the option has been available since v4.5.25. Setting that option will allow you to process items in any order.

Comment: I remember reading that `EnsureOrdered = false` is an optimization hint ignored by many blocks.  If you really need to ensure a random order, that would involve a custom `IPropagatorBlock` with a shuffle algorithm.  Trouble is, shuffling a sequence requires its length ahead of time, and thus a big ugly bottleneck in the data flow.